# No column specifiers declared for IEEEeqnarray

Tags: equations, ieee-style

I got an error message `No column specifiers declared for IEEEeqnarray` for the following description:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
a
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and whether or not you load the `IEEEtrantools` package.

Comment: A simple test document -- `\documentclass{IEEEtran} \begin{document} \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl} a \end{IEEEeqnarray} \end{document}` -- does *not* throw an error. Please explain what's different about your document relative to this test or reference document.